# How to make the navigation drawer header picture scrollable?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, navigation-drawer

I wanted to create a navigation drawer with a something like profile picture above the items of the list. Although I successfully created one but I have a problem on it: First the header picture the one with a circle image and the background also the text Ej Lungay is not scrollable. I wanted to make it scrollable, the moment that when i scroll down it must be also scroll down. I provided the image url below and the code:

[image]

Here is the sliding menu which contains the ListView and the Header of the navgation drawer:
fragment_sliding_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" > 

 <RelativeLayout 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
  android:background="@drawable/background_poly">
    <edu.ejapp.dotalegitstore.RoundedImage
        android:id="@+id/user_pic"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/hoiist" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/user"
        android:layout_below="@id/user_pic"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        /> 
 </RelativeLayout>  

<ListView
 android:id="@+id/list_view"
 android:divider="@color/gray_light"
 android:dividerHeight="0dip"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:listSelector="@color/app_main"
 android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And fragment_sliding_menu.xml is implemented here:
SlidingMenuFragment.java

```
public class SlidingMenuFragment extends Fragment {
List<String> data;
ListView list_view;
SlidingMenuListAdapter adapter;

@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sliding_menu, null);
    setUpView(root);
    return root;
}
void setUpView(ViewGroup root){
    list_view  =  (ListView)root.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    initList();
    setUpClick();
}
void initList(){
    data = new ArrayList<String>();

    data.add("Home");
    data.add("Arcana");
    data.add("Courrier");
    data.add("Hero Sets");
    data.add("Immortals");

    adapter = new SlidingMenuListAdapter(getActivity(),data);
    list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
}
void setUpClick(){
    list_view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    BaseActivity.mTitle="Home";
                break;

                case 1:
                    BaseActivity.mTitle="Arcana";
                break;
                case 2: 
                    BaseActivity.mTitle="Courrier";
                break;
                case 3:
                    BaseActivity.mTitle="Hero Sets";
                break;
                case 4:
                    BaseActivity.mTitle="Immortals";
                break;

                default:
                    BaseActivity.mTitle="Dota Legit Store";
                }
                MainActivity.closeDrawer();
            }
        });
}
}
```

And this is the ListView item: lis_view_sliding_menu_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView
    android:layout_margin="10dip"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
    android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And then the xml files are implemented in this class: SlidingMenuListAdapter.java

```
public class SlidingMenuListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
List<String>data;
Context context;
public SlidingMenuListAdapter(Context context,List<String> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_sliding_menu_items, null);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        //## Initial Views

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //## Setup Data below
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    TextView name = viewHolder.name;
    name.setText(data.get(position));
    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
}

}
```

Any other function of the program is working properly.

My question is: How can i make the header (please visit the image i provided above) scrollable like the list items (home, arcana, ...)? Please help me.. Im an android beginner. Any suggestion will be accepted will pleasure.

Comment: if you use android NavigationView it will do for you https://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html as per your  menu NavigationView is perfect

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion sir.